# Request to determine the quantity of a specific members in several classes linked together with a multiplier

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl, ontology

I've made a simplified example of my ontology in RDF/XML format.  It's at the end of the question. I work with Protégé 5.0 beta.

Picture that explains my request: 
[image]

I sum short:

- two level1 class : **process**, **products**
- three sub Class Of **process** : **process_1**, **process_2**, **process_3**
- each process has many own members which are linked to products members with a property **input** or **output**
- each members of process_n has data property called **quantity**.

If you could help me for the syntax it could be nice, but mostly it's on the reasoning I need help.

### Ontology (RDF/XML)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
<!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
<!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
<!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
<!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
<!ENTITY untitled-ontology-14 "http://www.semanticweb.org/francocy/ontologies/2015/1/untitled-ontology-14#" >
]>


<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/francocy/ontologies/2015/1/untitled-ontology-14#"
 xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/francocy/ontologies/2015/1/untitled-ontology-14"
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
 xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
 xmlns:untitled-ontology-14="http://www.semanticweb.org/francocy/ontologies/2015/1/untitled-ontology-14#"
 xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/francocy/ontologies/2015/1/untitled-ontology-14"/>

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;input"/>

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;output">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;FunctionalProperty"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;quantity"/>

<owl:Class rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;process"/>

<owl:Class rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;process_1">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;process"/>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;process_2">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;process"/>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;process_3">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;process"/>
</owl:Class>

<owl:Class rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;products"/>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;input_1_of_process_1">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;process_1"/>
    <quantity rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">5</quantity>
    <input rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;product_2"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;input_1_of_process_2">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;process_2"/>
    <quantity rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">3</quantity>
    <input rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;product_4"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;input_1_of_process_3">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;process_3"/>
    <quantity rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">2</quantity>
    <input rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;product_2"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;input_2_of_process_1">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;process_1"/>
    <quantity rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">2</quantity>
    <input rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;product_3"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;input_2_of_process_2">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;process_2"/>
    <quantity rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">10</quantity>
    <input rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;product_5"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;input_2_of_process_3">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;process_3"/>
    <quantity rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">3</quantity>
    <input rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;product_4"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;output_1_of_process_1">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;process_1"/>
    <quantity rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">1</quantity>
    <output rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;product_1"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;output_1_of_process_2">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;process_2"/>
    <quantity rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">1</quantity>
    <output rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;product_2"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;output_1_of_process_3">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;process_3"/>
    <quantity rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">1</quantity>
    <output rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;product_3"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;product_1">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;products"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;product_2">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;products"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;product_3">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;products"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;product_4">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;products"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-14;product_5">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-14;products"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: That's a pretty big ontology;  I bet it would be possible to create a more minimal example that would still work to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: You're right. I made another simplier example. owl : Image that explains the problem :

<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/sdbrvtpvsval8fb/problem_modified.png?dl=0">

And the ontology :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/n32t790dtr637ga/test-modified.owl?dl=0


Do you think it's better if I edit the first post with my new OLW and image ?

Comment: Yes, definitely edit/update the question

Comment: I edit the first post with the simplified problem. Sorry again.

Comment: It's *very* hard to follow the ontology with all the generated IRIs.  It's also not very clear how things are organized.  Where, for instance, is it stated that process 1 takes 5 elementaryProduct2 as input?

Comment: In fact, the UUID permit me to have the same labels in different processes.
If I don't use them, I have to change the labels of members for each process.

For your question, as input, the process1 need 5 elementaryProduct2 and 2 elementaryProduct3.
And to produce one elementaryProduct1 I need 9 elementaryProduct2 (5+2x2) and 6 elementaryProduct4 (2x3). Indeed, if we count the elementaryProduct2, we haven't to get the elementaryProduct4 linked to the process2. I know it's not obvious as reasoning.

Comment: I can follow the image, but I'm not clear how the OWL ontology that you've provided shows the same content.  I can understand that using the same label might be useful in places, but for the sake of a minimal example, it might be helpful to use more readable names like `process1_a`, `process1_b`, etc.  At any rate, when I search for process1 in this page, I see it only once in the ontology, and it's the name of a class.  From the image, it looks like it might be an individual.  Could you explain how you're representing process and their inputs?  It's not clear in your question yet.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.
I cogitated how to better explain my problem. So, I follow your idea to name only with label without IRIs. I edited the first post.
In my case, my processes are class items that gather many inputs and outputs. Each input and output are specific to each process. In other words, the inputs and outputs of one process define it.  These inputs and outputs are characterized by a "standard" product and a quantity.
Please let me know if it's not yet clear. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for so much cleaning and reworking of your ontology.  However, I still don't think it's a good way to capture what you're trying to express.  For instance your ontology includes, in N3 notation):

```
untitled-ontology-14:input_2_of_process_1
        a                              owl:NamedIndividual , untitled-ontology-14:process_1 ;
        untitled-ontology-14:input     untitled-ontology-14:product_3 ;
        untitled-ontology-14:quantity  2 .

untitled-ontology-14:input_1_of_process_1
        a                              owl:NamedIndividual , untitled-ontology-14:process_1 ;
        untitled-ontology-14:input     untitled-ontology-14:product_2 ;
        untitled-ontology-14:quantity  5 .

untitled-ontology-14:output_1_of_process_1
        a                              owl:NamedIndividual , untitled-ontology-14:process_1 ;
        untitled-ontology-14:output    untitled-ontology-14:product_1 ;
        untitled-ontology-14:quantity  1 .
```

These are three *instances* of the class **process_1**.  I don't think it makes sense that these are instances of a class called **process_1**.

Rather, I think that there is some distinct process, and it happens to have two inputs and one output.  Each input and output is a pair of a quantity and a particular product.

I'd represent your processes with something like this in N3 or RDF/XML. (I'm going to work in pure RDF for the moment; translating to OWL is just a matter of declaring some classes and properties; this is question about SPARQL, after all, and SPARQL is an *RDF query language*.)

```
@prefix : <urn:ex:> .

:process1 a :Process ;
          :hasInput  [ a :Measure ; :quantity 2 ; :product :product3 ] ,
                     [ a :Measure ; :quantity 5 ; :product :product2 ] ;
          :hasOutput [ a :Measure ; :quantity 1 ; :product :product1 ] .

:process2 a :Process ;
          :hasInput  [ a :Measure ; :quantity  3 ; :product :product4 ] ,
                     [ a :Measure ; :quantity 10 ; :product :product5 ] ;
          :hasOutput [ a :Measure ; :quantity  1 ; :product :product2 ] .

:process3 a :Process ;
          :hasInput  [ a :Measure ; :quantity 2 ; :product :product2 ] ,
                     [ a :Measure ; :quantity 3 ; :product :product4 ] ;
          :hasOutput [ a :Measure ; :quantity 1 ; :product :product3 ] .
```

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="urn:ex:">
  <Process rdf:about="urn:ex:process3">
    <hasInput>
      <Measure>
        <quantity rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
        >2</quantity>
        <product rdf:resource="urn:ex:product2"/>
      </Measure>
    </hasInput>
    <hasInput>
      <Measure>
        <quantity rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
        >3</quantity>
        <product rdf:resource="urn:ex:product4"/>
      </Measure>
    </hasInput>
    <hasOutput>
      <Measure>
        <quantity rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
        >1</quantity>
        <product rdf:resource="urn:ex:product3"/>
      </Measure>
    </hasOutput>
  </Process>
  <Process rdf:about="urn:ex:process2">
    <hasInput>
      <Measure>
        <quantity rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
        >3</quantity>
        <product rdf:resource="urn:ex:product4"/>
      </Measure>
    </hasInput>
    <hasInput>
      <Measure>
        <quantity rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
        >10</quantity>
        <product rdf:resource="urn:ex:product5"/>
      </Measure>
    </hasInput>
    <hasOutput>
      <Measure>
        <quantity rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
        >1</quantity>
        <product rdf:resource="urn:ex:product2"/>
      </Measure>
    </hasOutput>
  </Process>
  <Process rdf:about="urn:ex:process1">
    <hasInput>
      <Measure>
        <quantity rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
        >2</quantity>
        <product rdf:resource="urn:ex:product3"/>
      </Measure>
    </hasInput>
    <hasInput>
      <Measure>
        <quantity rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
        >5</quantity>
        <product rdf:resource="urn:ex:product2"/>
      </Measure>
    </hasInput>
    <hasOutput>
      <Measure>
        <quantity rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"
        >1</quantity>
        <product rdf:resource="urn:ex:product1"/>
      </Measure>
    </hasOutput>
  </Process>
</rdf:RDF>
```

This doesn't *solve* the problem, of course, and I'm not sure whether you can do all the computation you want with SPARQL, especially when there are multiple ways to produce various products, but you can at least start to write queries like this that will help you to figure out what you need to produce things, and which processes can help:

```
prefix : <urn:ex:>

select * where {
 ?process :hasOutput [ :quantity ?q ; :product :product1 ] ;
          :hasInput [ :quantity ?inputq ; :product ?input ] .
 ?input ^:product/^:hasOutput ?subprocess          
}
```

```
---------------------------------------------------
| process   | q | inputq | input     | subprocess |
===================================================
| :process1 | 1 | 5      | :product2 | :process2  |
| :process1 | 1 | 2      | :product3 | :process3  |
---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks you, you're right. Indeed, the inputs and outputs aren't really individuals of processes. Your proposal is better than mine.

Comment: @Cyril I'm not really sure that I follow what you're trying to say there.  However, I think that this *might* be solvable in SPARQL if each input is an output of at most one process.  The idea would be to use property paths to get a path to the "rightmost" input on each path, and then multiply the quantities along the path to find out how many are needed.  However, since there are multiple ways of producing some inputs (e.g., product 2), that approach wouldn't work, I think.